# Why does the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^3+y^3}$ not exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^3+y^3}$$
Hi, I would like to ask why its limit doesn't exist? Thank you.

Comment: What do you know about multivariable limits? What sorts of methods do you know for showing they do not exist?

Comment: If limits exist, they are unique. Can you evaluate this limit in two ways such that they do not yield the same answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determining existence of limit with multiple variables: $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{xy^2}{x^3+y^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185295/determining-existence-of-limit-with-multiple-variables-lim-x-y-to-0-0)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the limits on two ways:

1) First fix $x=0$ and consider the limit as $y$ approaches 0.

2) Along the path $y=x$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ on the $y$ axis, observe if there is a limit on this path.

Then, let $(x,y)=(t,t),$ as $t\to 0$, observe if there is a limit, if there is one compare it with the former.

Answer (score 0):

Along the line $y=x $, the limit is
$$\frac {1}{2} $$ and along $y=2x $, the limit is $$\frac{2}{9} $$
thus it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

To show that this limit does not exist, we need to show that there exists two paths to the point $(0,0)$ that approach different values.
1) Consider the path along $y = x$. Now $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^3+y^3} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2(x)}{x^3+(x)^3} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^3}{2x^3} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot$$
2) Consider the path along $y = 2x$. Now $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^3+y^3} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2(2x)}{x^3+(2x)^3} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{2x^3}{9x^3} = \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{2}{9} = \frac{2}{9}\cdot$$
Therefore, the $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2y}{x^3+y^3}$ does not exist.